# Is it possible to check whether my laptop is connected through a Wi-Fi or through a "wired LAN" programmatically in Windows C++?

Tags: c++, windows, wifi, lan

I need to know if my PC is communicating through WiFi, LAN, VPN… My application creates heavy network load and there is no point in launching in certain cases, that is why I need to know through which connection the PC communicates to the world…

Comment: "My application creates heavy network load" is that really the intent of your application or is that a bug? Usually this isn't needed except for games.

Comment: Couldn't you test the connection speed when you launch your application?

Comment: how are you communicating? How can we tell which network interface your app is using?

Comment: +1 for Emile Cormier. Test what you want to know, don't make assumptions. My private WiFi-N is faster than my corporate LAN at our branch office. As for assumptions "through which connection the PC communicates to the world" is the **WAN** connection, not the **LAN** so you are indeed making at least one wrong assumption there already.

Comment: OK. I understand that testing the speed can lead into the wrong conclusion, I really do not want to run my application over WiFi even if it very fast. My application seeks a network share like \\server\sharename\, which can be on the LAN or over VPN, and then will copy or read files to/from. I really do not know how this translates into network interface card. My aim is to prevent it from working if the channel is wireless.

Answer (score 0):

One brute force way might works:

The idea is to parse the ipconfig/ifconfig output.

First get a list of UP interfaces (e.g. lan0, wlan0) which are your candidates. Then send some data (e.g. ping google.com), compare the Rx packets and tx packets number before and after sending data and you should be able to get which interface is being used.

Hope this helps.